# What does "to be in the double digits to get inflation" mean?

Tags: inflation

> Until last year, the Chinese government set 8 percent annual growth as a goal, and the economy frequently delivered several percentage points more than that.
>   Then last March, the government pared the goal to 7.5 percent, and actual growth seems likely to be little higher.
>   “The potential growth rate of the economy has come down,” Stephen Green, a China economist in the Hong Kong offices of Standard Chartered, said Sunday. “**You don’t have to be in the double digits to get inflation**.”
>   Prices rose faster in December, according to government data released Friday. Consumer prices rose 2.5 percent from the level of a year earlier, their fastest pace since May.
>   [China Again Is Growing, More Slowly](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/14/business/global/as-chinas-economy-revives-so-do-fears-of-inflation.html)

Hi, I read this article and I do not understand what "be in the double digits" means here.
Could you please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Economists believe that higher growth rates tend to also mean higher inflation rates.

So in this case what Mr. Green means is that

> **You don't need a GDP growth rate of over 10% to get inflation.** (Even GDP growth of 7.5% or 8% will be enough for the return of high inflation.)

Comment: as a complement, it would be nice to say a bit more about how GDP growth translates into inflation