# Does Economic Growth Lead to Inflation?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, economic-growth

As an answer to [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/what-does-to-be-in-the-double-digits-to-get-inflation-mean/21141#21141), it was stated that

> Economists believe that higher growth rates tend to also mean higher
>   inflation rates.

As a non macro-economist, I am wondering if this is true? Is there any clear evidence on this relationship?

Higher growth may lead to higher demand and inflation but I guess this happens only if supply does not adjust and prices are not sticky.

The reverse causality running from [inflation to economic growth](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/inflation-and-economic-growth) does not seem to have much empirical support due to identification issues.

---

Moreover, [this paper](http://www.benoitmojon.com/pdf/Global-Inflation-REStat-proofs.pdf) shows that inflation in industrialized countries is largely a global phenomenon. The results provide a good starting point for exploring the hypothesis that inflation should, to some extent, be modeled as a global rather than a local phenomenon. I would interpret these results as going against a connection between (local) economic growth and inflation.

Comment: This may be an inverse of the Fed argument that inflation symbolizes growth.